# How to stop the subscription of a stream of a singleton class?

Tags: flutter, stream, subscription

How to stop the subscription of a stream of a singleton class, and when re-creating the subscription do not continue the data of that stream?

```
class MyClass {
  static MyClass _instance;

  factory MyClass() {
    _instance ??= MyClass._internal();
    return _instance;
  }

  MyClass._internal();

  final BehaviorSubject<Status> _streamController = BehaviorSubject<Status>();
  Stream<Status> get stream => _streamController.stream;
  Function(Status) get sink => _streamController.sink.add;

  StreamSubscription subscriptionImage;

  void dispose() {
    _streamController?.close();
  }

  void listen() {
    subscriptionImage = stream.listen((Status statusAnalysis) async {
      if (statusAnalysis.saving) {
        try {
          await patch(statusAnalysis);
        } on MyException catch (e) {}
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `subscriptionImage?.cancel();` before

```
subscriptionImage = stream.listen((Status statusAnalysis){...});
```

and you'll make sure that you cancel your previous subscription (if any) before creating a new one.

Comment: That stream to send images to the service, and I do not use it in a widget, but in a class, but for some reason after canceling the subscription the data flow continues its course and is not discarded

Comment: I see that when I call the listen method of this singleton class again, the code inside is executed

Comment: The only way it could get executed after being cancelled and re-subscribed, it’s because the asynchronous call could already be in progress and despite cancelling the subscription, you can’t actually cancel that ongoing call. You may want to take a look at [`CancelableOperation`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/CancelableOperation-class.html) for that.

Comment: I did the test with Cancelable Operation but I have the same result, in the end it ends up executing everything